# Sprite vs Group Collider not working in phaser with enableBody set as true

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I'm a bit new to JavaScript and have been playing around with Phaser lately. So I'm building an infinite side scroller and everything works fine except that my player won't collide with the walls. Both sprites have physics enabled and I have tried multiple solutions, none of which work. Can you please help me out?

```js
function bloxo()
{
 var game = new Phaser.Game(1200, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'gameStage', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
 var prevHole = 3;

 function preload() {
  game.load.image('bloxoDown','../bloxo/assets/images/bloxoDown.png');
  game.load.image('bloxoUp','../bloxo/assets/images/bloxoUp.png');
  game.load.image('wall','../bloxo/assets/images/platform.png',400,200);

  var space;
  var esc;
  var player;
  var walls;
  var score;
 }

 function create() {

  //Canvas With a White Bacground and Physics is Created
  game.stage.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);


  //Sets the initial Score.
  score = 0; 

  //Sets how fast the tiles move
  tileSpeed = -300;

  tileWidth = game.cache.getImage('wall').width;
  tileHeight = game.cache.getImage('wall').height;;

  //Keys for User Input are created
  space = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
  esc = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.ESC);

  //Adds Bloxo to the game as a sprite.
  player = game.add.sprite(200,200,'bloxoDown');
  player.scale.setTo(0.6, 0.6);
  game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  player.body.immovable = true;

  //Walls Group is created
  walls = game.add.physicsGroup();
  walls.createMultiple(50, 'wall');
  walls.enableBody = true;


  game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, walls,null,this)
  
  game.physics.arcade.collide(player,walls,gameOver);

  //  Stop the following keys from propagating up to the browser
  game.input.keyboard.addKeyCapture([ Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR, Phaser.Keyboard.ESC,]);

  //Unpausing Function
  window.onkeydown = function(event) 
     {  
         if (esc.onDown && (esc.timeDown > 2000))
         {   
          if(game.paused)
          {  
              game.paused = !game.paused;
              pauseLbl.destroy();
             }   
         } 
     }

     //Add an initial platform
  addWall();
 
  //Add a platform every 3 seconds
  var timerWorld = game.time.events.loop(500, addWall);
 }

 function update() {

  if (space.isDown)
     {
         player.body.y -=5;
         bloxoUp();
     }
     else
     {
      player.body.y +=5;
      bloxoDown();
     }

     if(esc.isDown)
     {
      pauseGame(); 
     }
 }

 function bloxoUp()
 {
  player.loadTexture('bloxoUp');
 }

 function bloxoDown()
 {
  player.loadTexture('bloxoDown');
 }

 function pauseGame()
 {
  game.paused = true;
  pauseLbl = game.add.text(500, 300, 'Game Paused', { font: '30px Roboto', fill: '#aaaaaa' });
 }

 function addTile(x,y)
 {
     //Get a tile that is not currently on screen
     var tile = walls.getFirstDead();
  
     //Reset it to the specified coordinates
     tile.reset(x,y);
     tile.body.velocity.x = tileSpeed; 
     tile.body.immovable = true;
  
     //When the tile leaves the screen, kill it
     tile.checkWorldBounds = true;
     tile.outOfBoundsKill = true;    
 }

 function addWall()
 {
     //Speed up the game to make it harder
     tileSpeed -= 1;
     score += 1;
  
     //Work out how many tiles we need to fit across the whole screen
     var tilesNeeded = Math.ceil(game.world.height / tileHeight);

     //Add a hole randomly somewhere
     do
     {
      var hole = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tilesNeeded - 2)) + 1;
   }while((hole > (prevHole + 2)) && (hole < (prevHole - 2)) );

   prevHole = hole;

     //Keep creating tiles next to each other until we have an entire row
     //Don't add tiles where the random hole is
     for (var i = 0; i < tilesNeeded; i++){
         if (i != hole && (i != hole+1 && i != hole-1) && (i != hole+2 && i != hole-2)){
             addTile(game.world.width, i * tileHeight); 
         }      
     }
 }

 function gameOver()
 {
  console.log("player hit");
  player.kill();
  game.state.start(game.state.current);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to move `collide` call into your update method:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, walls, gameOver);
```

Take a look to the runnable snippet below(I have resized the canvas for the preview, sorry) or [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/1ngpn681/):

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(450, 150, Phaser.CANVAS, 'gameStage', {
  preload: preload,
  create: create,
  update: update
});
var prevHole = 3;

function preload() {
  game.load.image('bloxoDown', '../bloxo/assets/images/bloxoDown.png');
  game.load.image('bloxoUp', '../bloxo/assets/images/bloxoUp.png');
  game.load.image('wall', '../bloxo/assets/images/platform.png', 400, 100);

  var space;
  var esc;
  var player;
  var walls;
  var score;
}

function create() {

  //Canvas With a White Bacground and Physics is Created
  game.stage.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);


  //Sets the initial Score.
  score = 0;

  //Sets how fast the tiles move
  tileSpeed = -300;

  tileWidth = game.cache.getImage('wall').width;
  tileHeight = game.cache.getImage('wall').height;;

  //Keys for User Input are created
  space = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
  esc = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.ESC);

  //Adds Bloxo to the game as a sprite.
  player = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'bloxoDown');
  player.scale.setTo(0.6, 0.6);
  game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  player.body.immovable = true;

  //Walls Group is created
  walls = game.add.physicsGroup();
  walls.createMultiple(50, 'wall');
  walls.enableBody = true;


  game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, walls, null, this)
  // remove your call to collide

  //  Stop the following keys from propagating up to the browser
  game.input.keyboard.addKeyCapture([Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR, Phaser.Keyboard.ESC, ]);

  //Unpausing Function
  window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (esc.onDown && (esc.timeDown > 2000)) {
      if (game.paused) {
        game.paused = !game.paused;
        pauseLbl.destroy();
      }
    }
  }

  //Add an initial platform
  addWall();

  //Add a platform every 3 seconds
  var timerWorld = game.time.events.loop(500, addWall);
}

function update() {

  if (space.isDown) {
    player.body.y -= 5;
    bloxoUp();
  } else {
    player.body.y += 5;
    bloxoDown();
  }
                                     
  // move your collide call here
  game.physics.arcade.collide(player, walls, gameOver);

  if (esc.isDown) {
    pauseGame();
  }
}
                                     
function bloxoUp() {
  player.loadTexture('bloxoUp');
}

function bloxoDown() {
  player.loadTexture('bloxoDown');
}

function pauseGame() {
  game.paused = true;
  pauseLbl = game.add.text(500, 300, 'Game Paused', {
    font: '30px Roboto',
    fill: '#aaaaaa'
  });
}

function addTile(x, y) {
  //Get a tile that is not currently on screen
  var tile = walls.getFirstDead();


  //Reset it to the specified coordinates
  if (tile) {
    tile.reset(x, y);
    tile.body.velocity.x = tileSpeed;
    tile.body.immovable = true;

    //When the tile leaves the screen, kill it
    tile.checkWorldBounds = true;
    tile.outOfBoundsKill = true;
  }

}

function addWall() {
  //Speed up the game to make it harder
  tileSpeed -= 1;
  score += 1;

  //Work out how many tiles we need to fit across the whole screen
  var tilesNeeded = Math.ceil(game.world.height / tileHeight);
  var prevHole;
  //Add a hole randomly somewhere
  do {
    var hole = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tilesNeeded - 2)) + 1;
  } while ((hole > (prevHole + 2)) && (hole < (prevHole - 2)));

  prevHole = hole;

  //Keep creating tiles next to each other until we have an entire row
  //Don't add tiles where the random hole is
  for (var i = 0; i < tilesNeeded; i++) {
    if (i != hole && (i != hole + 1 && i != hole - 1) && (i != hole + 2 && i != hole - 2)) {
      addTile(game.world.width, i * tileHeight);
    }
  }
}

function gameOver() {
  console.log("player hit");
  player.kill();
  game.state.start(game.state.current);
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 5px solid #333;
  margin-left:25px;
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would kiss you if I could. Thanks so much I coudn't understand why it wasn't working for hours because the tutorial I was working on said that the collide is in the create function. Again thanks so much!